# Random sample in R when data is in long format

Tags: r, sampling, random

I need to randomly sample a dataset which is arranged in long format. In my dataset, each subject has 4 observations, so if I randomly sample a row I am randomly losing one or more observation per subject.

This is a simulated data for illustration purposes, my data is much bigger.

```
sub sex group   dv1 dv2
P1  m   A   0.66    0.94
P1  m   B   0.98    0.26
P1  m   C   0.02    0.03
P1  m   D   0.60    0.30
P2  m   A   0.92    0.99
P2  m   B   0.82    0.09
P2  m   C   0.44    0.67
P2  m   D   0.53    0.80
P3  f   A   0.29    0.22
P3  f   B   0.46    0.20
P3  f   C   0.37    0.77
P3  f   D   0.76    0.54
P4  m   A   0.28    0.99
P4  m   B   0.16    0.57
P4  m   C   0.46    0.75
P4  m   D   0.28    0.21
```

In this example, I need to randomly select 2 males. For example, I tried using dplyr packaged (see below), but if I give a sample of 2, it just gives me 2 rows for `sex="m"` and 2 for `sex="f"`. In total, 4 randomly chosen rows. What I need it to do is to give me 8 rows where 4 come from one male and 4 from another. Changing grouping parameter to `sub` doesn't work, as it barks that there are only 2 levels in the group (actually, it would work in this toy example as there are 4 levels for each sub, but note that I am choosing like 50 samples from a bigger dataset). Also, it would just give me 2 random rows for each sub, which is not what I need.

```
library(dplyr)  
subset <- data %>%  
group_by(sex) %>%  
sample_n(2)
```

Please do not suggest to reshape the date to wide format and sample it there, as I know that I can do that. I am sure there must be a way to sample in long format.

Comment: Do you want to choose all of P1 observations if P1 is chosen, or only one observation from P1?

Comment: All of P1 observations. The problem with my solution is that I just get one observation per each sub, I want to keep all 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would sample from the patient names and then filter by those sampled names:

Look at all males

```
male_subset <- data %>% filter(sex == "m")
```

Look for unique male ID

```
male_IDs <- unique(male_subset$sub)
```

Sample from the unique IDs

```
sampled_IDs <- sample(male_IDs, 2)
```

Now you subset your data based on these sampled IDs:

```
data %>% filter(sub %in% sampled_IDs)
```

This should return all four rows for each of the 2 sampled individuals.

Comment: Great! This does what I want. Thank you very much @BarkleyBG

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've quite understood what you want. Would this do it?

```
data %>% filter(sex == 'm') %>% filter(sub %in% sample(paste0('P',1:4), 2))
```

You'd have to change what's in the `paste0` function for your real data, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't see to do what I need. With this code, I just get either 4 or 8 rows. At least the rows are for each subject (4 from each subject). What I need is to sample not rows, but subjects, where subject has data in more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

In base R,

```
set.seed(1)
subset<- sample(data[data$sex == "m",]$sub,2)
data_subset<-data[data$sub %in% subset,]
nrow(data_subset)
# [1] 8
```

Works, but not flashy.

Comment: I think there's a possibility that your 2 sampled ID's could be equal. If you dont look at unique ID's then you may sample the same person's ID twice, and then only have one person (and four rows) in the resulting data.frame instead of two people with 8 rows.

Comment: I've just tried this solution. It also works. I think the default behavior of sample() is 'replace = FALSE', so I think there won't be duplicates.

Comment: From `?sample()` "sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)" so I do not believe there would be an issue. However, I do prefer @BarkleyBG's solution. It is much more R-like.

Comment: Does `data[data$sex=="m",]$sub` contain repeat entries? If so, then there's a chance for a sample to randomly select the same entry multiple times, even without replacement. In fact, in this case it's guaranteed to do so when the number sampled (i.e. `size`) is greater than the number of males.

Comment: Ahhh, I get what you're saying now. Yes, you are right. It would need to be ... `sample(unique(data[data$sex=="m",]$sub,2)` ...  There actually is a chance that we do not get 2 unique subjects if we do not include `unique()`. Good call.